# How to create a tree view with ag-grid

Tags: angular, angular6, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

columnDefs is as below

```
columnDefs = [
{headerName: 'question', field: 'questionId', rowGroup:true
},
{headerName: 'type', field: 'type'
},
{headerName: 'answer', field: 'answers'
}
];
```

where answer is an array of strings.

```
export class Answer {
questionId:string;
type:string;
answers: [];
}
```

In a grid I am able to show this information in a single row but I would like to show all the answers in a tree view when user clicks on a question.
Also each answer in an array is a json string so I would like to parse it before showing on UI.
I tried to add rowGroup on question but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You need enterprise version of ag-grid first. And there in the documentation of ag-grid you can find how to implement tree data view https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree-data/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you requirements correctly, you are not looking for a tree, you are looking for a master-detail view:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/

Each question is displayed in the master grid, a questions answers are displayed in the detail-grid.